# Do Mule 3.5.0 supports synchronous for until-successful

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Currently I am using Mule Studio enterprise edition 3.5.0 ... By referring the following link :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope

I came to know that synchronous can be used in until-successful ... but whenever I try the following :-

```
<until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="5"  secondsBetweenRetries="10" failureExpression="#[header:INBOUND:http.status != 200]"  synchronous="true" doc:name="Until Successful">
<component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl" doc:name="JavaMain_ServiceImpl"/> 
</until-successful>
```

I am getting the following error :-

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'synchronous' is not allowed to appear in element 'until-successful'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) ...
```

Please help ...
Here is my Mule studio version :-
[image: Mule Version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported in `3.5.0-cascade`: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.5.0-cascade/modules/spring-config/src/main/resources/META-INF/mule.xsd#L6409

So if you're using `3.5.0-bighorn` or `3.5.0-andes`, you won't get this feature.

Comment: Hi David .. Thank you for your response .. Could you pls explain me now what I need to do to achieve it .. Do I need to download something like Mule Studio enterprise 3.5.0-cascade ?? Or need to change any schema location in the flow ?? Please help

Comment: Yes, the best is to download the latest Studio. This feature is BTW part of 3.5.0-cascade CE. Mulesoft doesn't provide it for download but you can easily build it from the GitHub tag, should you need a CE standalone distribution to run this app.

Comment: David, I have latest mule studio enterprise edition .. How can I build it from the GitHub tag ?? Any reference from where I can follow the steps ? and which application do I need to run in  CE standalone distribution ?can't it be run in enterprise edition standalone ?

Comment: If you're planning to use EE, then no worries, you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks David .. but pls help me by suggesting the steps or process I need to follow ... Can I get any reference link which I can follow to build it from the GitHub tag ?? How can I do it actually ?

Comment: You do not need to build anything if you are using 3.5.0-cascade EE. I was just mentioning the option to build 3.5.0-cascade CE in case you didn't want to use EE. But you've said you're OK with EE so you'll have no problem. Just use the latest Studio with cascade-EE.

Comment: Thanks David for your suggestion